# Why does helm ternary operator report "unrecognized type: string"

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Running helm v3.5.4.

I have a block of code in a helm chart that looks like this:

```
{{- if .Values.impacts_marketing_events }}
isMktgEventsImpacting: "Y"
{{- else }}
isMktgEventsImpacting: "N"
{{- end -}}
```

This works, but I wish it was a little more concise.

I read https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ternary and determined that the equivalent of this should be:

```
isMktgEventsImpacting: {{ ternary "Y" "N" .Values.impacts_marketing_events }}
```

However, when I run this through kubectl, it fails with "unrecognized type: string".

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I have to wrap the entire expression in double quotes.